# Sencha app build failed for native devices

Tags: android, extjs, build

sencha app build successed but sencha app build android or ios failed with below error

Sencha Cmd v7.4.0.45

[ERR] /Users/xxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.45/plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.45/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml:443: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.45/ant/build/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/xxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.45/ant/build/app/cordova-impl.xml:77: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/xxx/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.4.0.45/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:695: shellscript returned: 1

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved by installing gradle

brew install gradle

NOTE : if you are using M1 you rquired additional shell settings for brew (https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3.html)